# Discord py bot which only allows one word to be send in a selected channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to create a discord py bot that only allows the word "help" in a certain text channel. How would I do this? I have looked around online for the answer to my problem but I can only find a discord.js version. I was planning on adding it to my existing bot which is coded in discord.py. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Do you want a command or a message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message:discord.Message):
    if message.channel.id == "insert_id":
        if message.content == "help":
            "do something"
        else:
            await message.delete()
```

in the [on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) you use the [Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.Message) class which has a [channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.Message.channel) attribute. the channel attribute has an [id](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=textchannel#discord.abc.Messageable) if its not "help" just [delete](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message%20delete#discord.Message.delete) it

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have tried this and I couldnt get it to work. I then tried this code and it worked, but worked in every channel. as soon as I put in the if message.channel.id == 'id': part, then it doesnt work at all`@client.event
async def on_message(message):
        if 'help' in message.content:
          await client.process_commands(message)
        else:
          await message.delete()`

Comment: you in insert_id you have to put the real channel id like the integer without the ""
for example 
    if message.channel.id == 1234564897: